# Theory - How the resize is triggered by browser?

Tags: css, browser, media-queries

I have search for 1 hour to know (and get a viable source) how the resize is trigger in CSS (media) when it happens and by which component. **What I want it's how it works inside the browser, what it doing when the window is resize. Not the code.**
The goal of that is to create a sequence diagram to describe what is happening to resize for a course.

All I find is how to resize and other code result but not a point of theory *how it works*.

Thanks for incoming help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful -
:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia
:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio#Example

I'm also curious how the engine handles this, ill keep you posted

Comment: @jsbegginer Thanks, that help me for learn a little more, we will wait together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you know the following concepts
computed ,Viewport height, viewport width, viewport meta tag and media queries.

Viewport tag helps to set how you want to show your page in the mobile or desktop browser.

There are two types of events we need to look in for media queries to kick in by the browser.

Page Load and Page Resize.

1. Page Load:

   1. HTML is loaded first.
   2. CSS is parsed and applied to HTML.
   3. While parsing CSS generic CSS style gets applied first.
   4. Based on the viewport height and width media queries are executed and applied
2. Page Resize:

   1. CSS Media is the computed style. So the viewport height or width changes makes the media queries to execute and apply.

Answer (score 3):

There is a little bit of vagueness in your question: I'm not sure whether you are asking about HTML's `resize` event or how CSS's `@media` queries respond to resizing. So I will address them separately.

---

### HTML's `resize` Event

This is an event fired by `window`, targeted at `window`, and can currently only be listened to by `window`, although ["[t]here is a proposal to allow all elements to be notified of resize changes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event). This is just a regular DOM event so external Javascripts may attach listeners to `window` and basically do whatever they want. If you are interested in how DOM events work, then you should probably just read [documentation by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) because they do a better job than I ever would.

---

### CSS `@media` 'Reacting' to Resize Events

Notice 'Reacting' is in quotes because CSS really doesn't care if any event fired, and it isn't really reacting. You should read [this excellent article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/inside-browser-part3) by Google on how the page renderer works in browsers. Words cannot do this article justice on just how well-written it is, but I will try giving a brief summary on the part you are interested in.

#### TLDR;

The page renderer is an empirical loop in nature, not event-driven. It simply uses the part of CSS it needs when it needs it. In the case of `@media` queries, it simply checks if the queries match the current states at the time of render, and apply them if they do. It then does this all over again in the next iteration.

#### Slightly more specifically:

On page load, the main thread first receives the HTML, builds the DOM tree, and loads requested resources including CSS (overlooking preload scanner since it's irrelevant to the question). It then parses the CSS and calculates the computed style for each element, before passing the DOM with computed style attached to the renderer thread. The renderer performs layout, paint, composite, and sends the final composite frame to the GPU. You can read more about these individual procedures in the linked Google article.

Now the browser runs at some framerate, typically 60. So the renderer has to push 60 composite frames to the GPU every second. Obviously it's stupid to recalculate all of these for every frame, so the entire process is cached at every stage. If nothing happened between two frames, then the renderer just pushes the last calculated frame. If some event has fired between two frames, then the browser attempts to update the frame with as little work as possible. For example, if you are typing something into a textbox, there is no need to recalculate the computed style.

If an event like `resize` did fire during the interval between two frames however, computed style recalculation is necessary. So the main thread simply reads through the CSS, and ignores the `@media` queries that don't match the states for the current frame. Then it calculates the new computed style and passes that to the renderer. The renderer does its job from there.

Obviously I am overlooking a lot of performance optimisation details that exist in all modern browsers, but here's the gist of the entire process. Again, go read the Google article. It explains everything very clearly (with illustrations too!).

Answer (score -2):

**Media Queries working this way.**

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

       <a data-viewport="375×667">iPhone 6</a>


// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Comment: I know that, what I want it's how it works inside the browser, what it doing when the window is resize.